# best location for multiscreen/tabbed view toggle button

Tags: toggle

The application i'm working on can be displayed either on multiple monitors or as tabs on 1 monitor. 
All the top-level controls will be located on 1 (main) screen and additional screens will display whatever is in tabs. 
In attached mock-up you can see that i have 3 positions left where this button can be placed. I feel it should be on the left side of the second level of menu, but i would love to hear what you think.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

I feel `multi-screen` is a user option, so it should be next to `user controls`. Besides, putting it on the `2nd level controls` wouldn't it be relegating it to "secondary" importance?

Firefox puts their "tab groups manager" icon right along the tabs:

[image: firefox group tabs]